# Faulhaber's Formula proof

Tags: bernoulli-numbers

I'm going through the proof from the book 'Bernoulli Numbers and Zeta Functions' and there's a step that I don't understand. My best guess at the minute is Taylor series. (It's the line highlighted in yellow in the image) Thanks

> Similarly, taking the derivatives successively, we obtain
> $$
> S_{k}^{(j)}(0)=k(k-1) \cdots(k-j+2) b_{k-j+1} \quad(2 \leq j \leq k+1)
> $$
> Finally, we have
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \color{red}{S_{k}(x)} &=\sum_{j=0}^{k+1} \frac{S_{k}^{(j)}(0)}{j !} \color{red}{x}^{j} \\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^{k+1} \frac{1}{k+1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
> k+1 \\
> j
> \end{array}\right) b_{k-j+1} x^{j} \quad\left(S_{k}^{(0)}(0)=0\right) \\
> &=\frac{1}{k+1} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\left(\begin{array}{c}
> k+1 \\
> j
> \end{array}\right) b_{j} x^{k+1-j}
> \end{aligned}
> $$

Comment: It appears a Taylor expansion was used of sorts, but you haven't shown us what $S_k(x)$ is.  Another approach would be to apply the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula, which also works since the $n$th derivative eventually becomes identically zero.

Comment: S(k,x) = sum from i=1 to x of (i^k)

Comment: Well, you have a problem then.  You can't differentiate with respect to $x$.

Comment: Sure you can.  $S_1(x) = x(x+1)/2$,  $S_2(x) = x(x+1)(2x+1)/6$, $S_3(x) = x^2(x+1)^2/4$, etc.  For each natural value of $k$, the sum can be simplified to a closed form which is a polynomial in $x$, and you can differentiate the polynomial with respect to $x$.  The formula in question is just the usual Taylor series expansion of the polynomial centered at $0$

Comment: @BarrySmith But its not directly differentiable from the definition of $S$.  Note that$$S_1(x)=\frac{(1+\sin(2\pi x))x(x+1)}2$$is also valid, according to the original definition.

Comment: I'm using the number-theoretic context here.  Presumably, there's a comment in the omitted part of the text that these are to be interpreted as polynomials in $x$.

Comment: Yes, earlier on in the book he proves that S is a polynomial in x with leading term of degree (k+1) (my apologies)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $S_k(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n i^k$, which is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $k+1$. This is just Taylor's formula applied to this polynomial (remeber Taylor's formula at order $k+1$ is a exact formula for polynomials of degree $\le k+1$.

Comment: Yes, but how does one effectively define this for non-integer $n$ for differentiation purposes?

Comment: The differentiation of the S function is with respect to i rather than x so S'k(x)= sum of (ki^(k-1)) for instance.

Comment: @Jacamo That can't possibly make sense.  $i$ is fixed, and set to be $i=\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art: You replace $n$ with an indeterminate and apply formal differentiation of polynomials.

Comment: @Bernard Could you expand on that?  I'd really like to see how that'd work out fully.

Comment: It's quite simple. For instance, since $S_3(n)=\frac14n2(n+1)^2$, you set $S_3(X)=\frac14X^2(X+1)^2$, and have $S'_3(X)=\frac12X(X+1)^2+\frac12X^2(X+1)$, $S''_3(X)=\frac12((X+1)^2+4X(X+1)+X^2$, $S'''(X)=3(2X+1)$, $S^{(4)}(X)=6$, so $S(0)=S'(0)=0$, $S''(0)=\frac12$, $S'''(0)=3$.